# How to send a JSON file to Amazon SQS queue using BOTO

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I need to send a couple of .json file to AWS SQS queueing service. Can someone tell me what exact code using boto will accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along those lines should work:
(You may check the syntax first, I haven't tested this )

```
import boto.sqs
import json

queue_name = 'YOUR-QUEUE'
sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
queue = sqs.get_queue(queue_name)

[queue.write(queue.new_message(json.load(i))) for i in ['file1.json', 'file2.json']]
```

Comment: It throws:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some_cooljso.py", line 14, in <module>
    [queue.write(queue.new_message(json.load(i))) for i in ['emp.json', 'emp2.json']]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: i needed to open the file before putting it in the for loop

Comment: Using a list comprehension while relying on "side-effects" feels icky.

Answer (score 0):

Boto's `new_message()` call is expecting a string as its argument.  Your files are already storing the JSON in string format.  You don't need the JSON module.  Just don't forget to strip your line endings - \r\n on Windows (CRLF) and \n on Unix (LF)

If, however, you have a JSON object then that is a different story.  Use `json.dumps` to take your JSON object and dump it as a string.

[From the boto (not version 3) docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/sqs_tut.html#listing-all-queues) on connect_to_region()

```
At this point the variable conn will point to an SQSConnection object in the US-WEST-2 region. Bear in mind that just as any other AWS service, SQS is region-specific. In this example, the AWS access key and AWS secret key are passed in to the method explicitly. Alternatively, you can set the environment variables:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID - Your AWS Access Key ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY - Your AWS Secret Access Key
```

I tested this on python 2.7.12 and boto (not boto 3) and it worked.

```
import boto.sqs
import sys

# either use environment variables for your access keys, or the flags here
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-west-2", aws_access_key_id="the_key", aws_secret_access_key="the_secret_key")
q = conn.get_queue('the_queue_name')

if not q:
  print "unable to locate queue!  exiting..."
  sys.exit()

for src_file in ['myfile1.json', 'myfile2.json']:
  with open(src_file, 'r') as json_file:
    for line in json_file:
      print "writing %s" % line
      q.write(q.new_message(line.rstrip('\r\n')))
```